# How Do I Retrieve Assoc. Array With Cdbcriteria in Yii

Tags: arrays, yii, jqgrid, associative

I have in my model Events the code generated method **search()**, which returns with $this->search()->data an array of Events objects. However I want to have an associative array of Events data for my jqGrid with **CDbCriteria** not `Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->Select('...')->From('...')->Where('...')`.

Any idea how to do that with:

```
public function search(){

$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
$criteria->compare('Date',$this->Date,true);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new function in your model: Let's say your model name is User.

```
    public static function getValues($criteria){
            $array_result = array();
            $results = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
            foreach($results as $result){
                    $array_result[$result->id] = $result->date;        
            }
            return $array_result;
    }
```

You can replace $result->id with whatever you want as Key, and $result->date with whatever values you want on the array. You can retrieve results by passing in the criteria to the function. If you want you can remove the criteria parameter, and just fetch all results or specify the criteria inside the function if you don't need it to be very dynamic.